# VBA EXCEL copy range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I posted the same question a little while ago and was told that I had spelled sheets wrong. I took the question down; because I thought that I understood I was trying to call a method..that was my range (and yes sheet was spelled sheeet). I guess I still do not understand. I am trying to copy column "A2" through the last cell of column "D" from the sheet "TEXT" to Sheet3

```
Dim TotalRows As Integer
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook ' macro workbook
Dim RangeToCopy As Range
Dim ColumnLetterNumber As String

Set CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
TotalRows = Sheets("TEXT").UsedRange.Rows.Count
ColumnLetterNumber = "D" & TotalRows


Set RangeToCopy = Range("A2", ColumnLetterNumber)

' Group Last Observed within the first three columns
' Last Observed start in column N
' After Insert end up in column )

 Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

' Move the Last observed (now column O) to Column D so that they can be fitered together

Sheets("TEXT").Range(Range("O1"), Range("O1").End(xlDown)).Copy Sheets("TEXT").Range("D1")

With Sheets("TEXT")
 .AutoFilterMode = False
 .Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter
End With
'
'Copy Columns to the POAM sheet
Set RangeToCopy = Range("A2", ColumnLetterNumber) 'top left, bottom right
RangeToCopy.Select
CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Activate


CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("TEXT").Range(RangeToCopy).Copy Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1"), unique:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, What error are you getting and also when you step through the code what line does it stop at?

Comment: A lot of your calls to `Range` aren't qualified with a sheet name and will default to the active sheet. That will be OK if "TEXT" is active but will fail if any other sheet is active when the macro runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your more detailed earlier question.  This will not work because this line doesn't work for at least 2 reasons:

```
CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("TEXT").Range(RangeToCopy).Copy Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1"), unique:=True
```

First, "RangeToCopy" is not a defined range on the sheet, so you cannot reference it in this way.  It is a variable in your VBA code, so you just need to use the Copy Function on this range.  Second, the Copy function of the Range Class does not have all of these parameters.  You want:

```
RangeToCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
```

If you are actually tryin get unique values, then  you need to use the "AdvancedFilter" function.

```
RangeToCopy.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1"), unique:=True,  criteriarange:= <Insert range that you wish to get unique values from here>
```

Also, you should define RangeToCopy based on the Sheet Name so:

```
Set RangeToCopy = Sheets("TEXT").Range("A2", ColumnLetterNumber)
```

Comment: This works, I did not understand that when creating and or assigning a range the sheet name should be included.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you over doing this?

```
Sub Macro()

    Dim dEnd As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("D1").Select
    dEnd = Selection.End(xlDown).Row

    Range("A2:" & "D" & dEnd).Copy

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

(I didn't bother with sheet names)

Comment: I didn't take into account that D could have empty rows, but I'm sure you can work that out yourself.

Comment: The prior post works, I'm interested in the compressed format that you used. I will added the code for unique values.